# Perché i cuochi abusano nell'uso di "vado", "andiamo", "andrò" e simili?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Siamo invasi da trasmissioni televisive nelle quali si vede un cuoco che cucina e intanto spiega i passaggi. Questi cuochi, evidentemente, condividono un modo di parlare che non riesco più ad ascoltare, talmente mi urta; una frase come

> ora trito il prezzemolo che metterò nella salsa, e poi  accenderò il forno

diventa

> ora vado a tritare il prezzemolo che andrò a mettere nella salsa, e poi andrò ad accendere il forno

Questo linguaggio si può anche ascoltare per cinque minuti, ma trascorsi quelli diventa insopportabile. Sembra che questi cuochi percorrano chilometri, invece lavorano a un piano di lavoro di un metro per due. Mi sono chiesto se si tratti di un'abitudine di chi spiega mentre lavora: non guardo molto quel tipo di trasmissioni (a parte quelle dei cuochi perché sono costretto), ma mi pare di no.

Ora chiedo: qualcuno ne sa qualche cosa di più? Qualcuno ha qualche idea per limitare questo fenomeno che è un vero linguicidio? Spero che qualche linguista (o almeno amante della nostra lingua) raccolga questo appello, e chieda una volta in diretta TV:

> **Perché diavolo voi cuochi parlate così?**

*********** AGGIUNTA DOPO I COMMENTI *********

Forse i cuochi usano il verbo andare non come alternativa figurata al modo futuro, ma per dare enfasi e movimento alla scena che forse ritengono troppo statica (sicuramente i movimenti di un cuoco sono più contenuti rispetto a quelli di un ballerino o di un giocatore di calcio). Non sono sicuro, però ci sono altri spettacoli come quelli floreali, quelli sul fai-da-te, o attività giocose per bambini, dove non si usano frasi così strampalate.

Se davvero è così, significa che i cuochi si stanno scimmiottando a vicenda: la cosa può essere interessante (oltre che fastidiosa).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104946/discussion-on-question-by-linuxfan-says-reinstate-monica-come-impedire-che-i-cuo).

Comment: La domanda non è ben formulata. Il modo di dire è veramente fastidioso, ma qui si discute di lingua italiana e non di estetica. Si può certamente chiedere l'origine del fastidiosissimo modo di dire. Come evitarlo? Cambiando canale quando qualcuno parla di cucina.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In una mia risposta https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11566/6017 sostenevo che una certa costruzione di frase, trovata in un discorso, potrebbe NON corrispondere a una certa accezione riportata da un dizionario semplicemente perchè l'intenzione del parlante non era quella di usare quella tale accezione.
(Se qualcuno trova errori di forma nel periodo precedente, me lo segnali).

Avrei voluto rispondere nell'altra pagina ma è impossibile, quindi lo faccio qui dove, tutto sommato, non è fuori posto.

Dato che non citavo fonti, ora le cito e approfondisco il mio pensiero.

Il GDLI (la fonte di Charo, http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000463.jpg), riporta a sua volta altre tre fonti che sono queste:

Arlia, 30: si arieggia ... **quando si dice** *vado a dirvelo* **invece di** *ora ve lo dico*
Rigutini-Cappuccini, 12: [è brutto gallicismo dire] *vo a fare* **denotando** azione che si stia per incominciare
Panzini IV-24: [risponde al francese] *andare a* **non nel senso di muoversi**

Si legga attentamente: ognuna delle tre fonti, inequivocabilmente, restringe il caso di applicazione del costrutto descritto, richiamando il concetto di intenzione di chi lo usa;
questo richiamo è espresso dalle parole "si dice ... invece di ...", "denotando azione che ...", "*andare a* non nel senso di muoversi".

D'altra parte, si consideri che molte parole italiane hanno più di un significato: se si legge "imposta" non si può assumere a priori che si tratti di un tributo: serve il contesto per capire se il significato è "tassa/tributo/contributo" oppure "persiana/gelosia" (e questi ultimi a loro volta possono significare altro). Lo stesso ragionamento vale per le perifrasi, ma è più difficile perché il contesto risulta sfumato.

Si può essere ragionevolmente sicuri, leggendo "chiudi la persiana", che l'accezione intesa dal parlante era quella di "serramento" e non quella di "donna di Persia". Ma se si legge "vado a dormire", il significato è "vado a letto" come in Boccaccio Decameron I-Concl. (120) "Andarsi a dormire", oppure si tratta della barbara costruzione gallica "sono in procinto di" / "mi appresto a"?

Vi sono riportati, in quella fonte, altri esempi della stessa costruzione, senza analisi alcuna. Dato che ritengo che l'uso del francesismo di cui parliamo non sia comune, forse perché scoraggiato o forse perché gli italiani non lo apprezzano, ho cercato di trovare
delle spiegazioni con qualche esempio.

"**Andare a ...**" può essere usato per denotare l'inizio di un'azione: andare a dormire, andare a lavarsi, andare a mangiare. Ci sono ambiguità perché a volte cominciare l'azione implica lo spostamento fisico (andare in camera da letto, bagno, sala da pranzo), ma l'esempio del Boccaccio non è ambiguo.

"**Andare a ...**" si può usare per spostare l'enfasi sulle cause o le ragioni invece che sul verbo in sé:
Andare a vedere: controllare, intraprendere l'azione di guardare
Andare a pensare: il processo mentale che porta a una conclusione, piuttosto della conclusione in sé: "andare a pensare che sia una truffa è sbagliato", "sono andato a pensare cose indicibili".

Per esempio, se il titolo del romanzo "L'Agnese va a morire" fosse invece "L'Agnese morirà", sarebbe un titolo brutto.
Il romanzo descrive la vita di Agnese che, per scelta sua, aiuta i partigiani esponendosi a grandi rischi, che le saranno fatali. Il titolo perciò riassume gli eventi che hanno portato alla morte di Agnese, spostando l'enfasi dal
suo morire a tutto quanto è successo prima.

"**Andare a ...**" può essere usato come ampollosità verbale per enfatizzare o, nei buoni casi, per aggiungere gravità o serietà o rispetto, similmente a costruzioni come "persone venute a mancare" (detto da Enrico Mentana, parlando dei morti a causa del COVID19).  Io ravviso questo uso rispettoso e grave, e pure un po' enfatico, anche nel titolo "L'Agnese va a morire".

Quest'ultimo uso ampolloso è quello fatto probabilmente dai cuochi, perchè loro usano "andare a" in tutti i modi verbali:

- "vado a tritare i pinoli" (mentre già lo sta facendo)
- "andremo a metterlo al forno" (il futuro è già nel verbo, e mi astengo dal criticare altri particolari)
- "andrei a cuocerlo di più ma non c'è tempo"
- "se andassimo a impiattarlo ora..."
- "siamo andati a sfumare col vino" (facendo il riassunto a posteriori)
- "andando così a dare un tocco asprigno"

e viene quindi a mancare l'intenzione di "mi appresto a", e anche quasi sempre lo spostamento fisico.

Comment: Ho dato io il voto negativo. Non ho aggiunto un commento, perché ne ho messi già fin troppi su questo argomento (qui, spostati in chat, e nella domanda di Charo); non voglio intasare il sito, quello che ho da dire sull'argomento sta lì.

Comment: Sono in disaccordo con il contenuto di questa risposta perché [l'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/andiamo-a-servire-la-risposta/1103), analizzando l'uso di *andare a* + infinito «in trasmissioni in cui si insegna a cucinare, cucire o creare qualcosa», ne fa questa interpretazione: «La costruzione *andare a* + infinito nei casi che vengono proposti all’attenzione rientra nelle cosiddette perifrasi imminenziali, che collocano l’evento – che ancora non si è realizzato – in un futuro prossimo.» (Per averne più dettagli si legga l'articolo completo.)

Comment: @Charo Grazie per l'articolo che segnali, è interessante. Ed è  anche approfondito, tanto che prima spiega le perifrasi imminenziali e poi le abbandona passando ad altre spiegazioni che assomigliano alle mie. Quindi non è in *netto contrasto* con quanto ho scritto qui.

Answer (score -3):

Riformulo la mia risposta anche se ho l'impressione che il post iniziale sia stato modificato (non importa da chi). "Andare a+ infinito" non è una costruzione canonica in italiano per esprimere un futuro imminente del tipo "vado a tagliare"=fra poco taglierò". "Vado a tagliare" si usa quando uno deve spostarsi per compiere l'azione designata. Ora il discorso è: si sta sviluppando in italiano una costruzione con "andare" per descrivere un futuro imminente senza movimento come in inglese "I am going to stay at home" e in francese "je vais rester chez moi"? Penso questa fosse l'intenzione di chi ha chiesto visto che parla di persone che non si spostano.

Comment: Come mai il downvote?

Comment: Forse perché non hai fornito nessuna fonte a sostegno della tua risposta. Da quanto emerge nei commenti il conio è tutt’altro che novello. (Not my DV btw).

Comment: Ho messo io il voto negativo. 1) Non rispondi alla domanda, che io trovo poco sensata (e ho a sua volta votato negativamente), ma che comunque è “Come impedire che i cuochi etc.”. 2) Sembri ignorare il fatto che la costruzione che stiamo discutendo non è né nuova né censurabile. Non so che cosa intendi per “costruzione canonica”, ma è una costruzione che si usa e si comprende da almeno un secolo e mezzo. Molto più di “neutrino”, per esempio.

Comment: No, "vado a" nel senso futuro che spiego sopra non si usa normalmente in italiano. Dici forse "vado a raccontarti una storia"??Sull'identità del "votatore" non avevo comunque dubbi..

Comment: Questa risposta almeno un dubbio cerca di toglierlo: sostiene che l'uso del verbo andare come usato dai cuochi non è italiano normale. Per il fatto di citare fonti, come si fa a citare fonti non positive? Per esempio, come potrei citare fonti se sostengo che il verbo "lavare" non è usato in senso figurato al posto di "pensare"?

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG: quello che spiega questa risposta è in contraddizione con quello che riportano il Treccani e il GDLI (si vedano i commenti nella chatroom) sulla costruzione "andare + infinito" col significato di "stare per, incominciare, essere imminente" o "essere in procinto di", che "è un francesismo, a lungo censurato e sconsigliato, oggi molto com." (nel GDLI si vede esplicitamente come era stato censurato nell'Ottocento e all'inizio del Novecento).

Comment: @Nico: Io non lo dico, ma altri italiani anche d'altri tempi (come Nino Bixio) sì: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1362&bih=925&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk018d8UJW5hmuKwXlqCC12KYFyTKXQ%3A1582800112130&ei=8JxXXtbPB4XLrgTD2qAg&q=%22vado+a+raccontarti%22&oq=%22vado+a+raccontarti%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11452.15560.0.16053.22.19.0.0.0.0.239.2296.0j9j4.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..14.3.514...0j33i10k1.0.ATYF53NY-6g

Comment: E c'è anche il titolo del famoso romanzo di Renata Viganò, *L'Agnese va a morire*.

Comment: @charo Vista la trama del romanzo, mi sembra molto più plausibile una lettura alla lettera (Agnese va in un posto vicino al suo paese, dove viene uccisa) rispetto a una lettura di "andare" come ausiliare per il futuro del tipo "Agnese sta per morire".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Sembra siamo gli unici a cui frasi del tipo "adesso vado a spiegarti il problema" non si sentono correntemente.

Comment: Mi corre l'obbligo :-) di segnalare che a me "L'Agnese va a morire" non da' un senso di futuro imminente, ma piuttosto di "complemento di destino", così come "andiamo a incominciare" e "andare a male". E pure "ora vado a tritare il prezzemolo" (i cuochi lo dicono proprio così - parola di cuoco).

Comment: @Nico forse diverse persone hanno prestato poca attenzione alle trasmissioni di cucina ma, con una pulce nell'orecchio, magari cambiano idea.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica A parte quelle trasmissioni resto dell' opinione che "andare a" si usi poco in italiano standard. Per me non esiste una costruzione grammaticalizzata in italiano come in francese "aller à". Nessuno direbbe mai "adesso vado a scrivere una email" mentre è seduto davanti al computer...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica La vedo esattamente come te. Infatti si dice anche "milioni di persone andarono a morire nei campi di concentramento" e questo non c'entra nulla con il futuro.

Comment: @DaG Sembra che i tuoi commenti contengano una teoria plausibile sulla storia e sulla legittimità di questa costruzione. Avresti voglia di formularla come una risposta? Specialmente su una domanda controversa come questa, è importante che tutte le opinioni compaiano come risposte anziché come commenti, secondo me, per come funziona il sistema di Stack Exchange.

Comment: Grazie, @FedericoPoloni, ma sulla costruzione in sé “andare a + inf.” c'è [un'altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/origine-della-costruzione-andare-a-infinito-come-sinonimo-di-stare-per-i) con un paio di risposte valide. Qui non so quale sia la domanda, se quella del titolo o una di quelle contenute nel testo, ma in ogni caso non so nulla sull'italiano dei cuochi.