# Origine della costruzione "andare a" + infinito come sinonimo di "stare per" + infinito

Tags: phrase-origin

In [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11561/) si è spiegato che i cuochi che appaiono in televisione spesso si esprimono usando frasi come, ad esempio,

> Vado a impiattare

col significato di

> Sto per impiattare

oppure

> Ora impiatterò.

Qual è l'origine di questo tipo di costruzioni nella lingua italiana?

Comment: Di spiegazioni ne avrei se non fosse che questa non è a mio avviso una costruzione grammaticalizzata (i.e. diffusa e standardizzata) in italiano.

Comment: Io sono poco o nulla sicuro che con "vado a impiattare" il cuoco intenda "sto per impiattare". Bisognerebbe chiederlo a lui...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Io credo che lo usi solo se si muove da un posto all'altro di una cucina enorme, come si usa "vado a raccogliere il prezzemolo in giardino" detto quando si è in cucina.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Come suggerito in un commento alla domanda precedente, secondo [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/andare1/) è un francesismo che sembra essersi diffuso nel linguaggio comune:

> Seguìto dalla preposizione a e un infinito, ***essere in procinto di, stare per:***
>
> - *gli sta peggio quel malato e pare che vada a morire* (Fucini); tranne rari casi, nei quali (come nell’esempio ora dato) ha accezioni di tono particolare, ***è un francesismo, a lungo censurato e sconsigliato, oggi molto comune*** (così, per es.: *il passo che ora vado a leggervi, per il più semplice «che ora vi leggerò»; lo spettacolo va a incominciare, per «sta per cominciare»).*

E la seguente risposta da parte [dell’Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/andiamo-a-servire-la-risposta/1103) ad una domanda simile nota che:

> È infatti nelle numerose trasmissioni televisive legate al cibo e alla cucina e nei canali del web che *andare a* + infinito sembra aver trovato una sorta di zona franca, da cui poi irradiarsi nell’uso di ambiti più generici. I luoghi dell’italiano gastronomico sono occasione e veicolo di forme e parole (come *impiattare*, *impiattamento*), che sembrano comunicare un valore estetico o simbolico o presuntivamente dinamico della lingua.
> Certamente nell’uso ‘gastronomico’ di *andare a* + infinito si sente
> una marca di intenzionalità, di progettualità dell’azione, ai fini
> della migliore riuscita.

Comment: Complimenti per la nota dell'Accademia, che si attaglia bene alla domanda e parla di progettualità più che d'imminenza.

Comment: Sono invece in disaccordo con la Crusca riguardo alla voce *impiattare* perchè credo che non abbia alcunchè di simbolico o dinamico; mi pare piuttosto un'invenzione praticamente necessaria per esprimere chiaramente e concisamente l'atto e l'arte di porre nel piatto il cibo appena preparato. L'*impiattamento* è oggetto di voto (oltre a tecnica e qualcos'altro) in una trasmissione giornaliera (posso dire "prandiale"?) di RAI 1.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Qui abbiamo una riconferma del fatto che "andare a"  è gergo dei cuochi e non una costruzione usuale in italiano per indicare il futuro, a differenza di quanto asserito da diversi utenti qui.

Comment: Anch'io trovo molto interessante l'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca e penso valga la pena leggerlo tutto completo. Comincia così: «La costruzione *andare a* + infinito nei casi che vengono proposti all’attenzione rientra nelle cosiddette perifrasi imminenziali, che collocano l’evento – che ancora non si è realizzato – in un futuro prossimo.»

Comment: @Charo, sarebbe come dici tu (anzi, la Crusca), se i cuochi non usassero altre frasi come "sarei andato a", "siamo andati a", "così andremo a", "mi andrà a dare" e simili. Per loro l'importante è usare il verbo andare.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000463.jpg), questa costruzione col significato di "stare per, incominciare, essere imminente" era già in uso nella lingua italiana nell'Ottocento. Questo vocabolario riporta alcuni esempi dell'Ottocento e dell'inizio del Novecento in cui si può vedere come era censurata come francesismo:

> - Si arieggia al modo francese quando si dice: ' Vado  a  dirvelo ',  invece  di  ' Ora  ve  lo  dico,  sto  per  dirvelo '  ;  ' Vado  a  farlo ',  invece  di  ' Ora  lo  faccio ',  o  ' Lo farò  subito '.  Dunque  è  errato  il  dire:  ‘  La  predica  va a  cominciare ' (Costantino Arlìa, *Lessico dell’infima e corrotta italianità*, Carrara-Milano, 1890; 1ª edizione, 1881).
> - ' Vo  a  fare,  a dire ',  ecc.  denotando  azione  che  si  stia  per  incominciare, 
>     è  brutto  gallicismo (*je vais faire, dire*): ' State attento alla formula  del  giuramento  che  ora  vado  a  leggervi ',  suol  dire 
>     il  giudice  al  testimone;  e  dovrebbe  dire ' che  sono  per  leg­gervi ',  o  ' che  ora  vi leggo ' (Giuseppe Rigutini e Giulio Cappuccini, *I neologismi buoni e cattivi*)<sup>1</sup>.
> - *Andare a*, non  nel  senso  materiale  di  muoversi,  come *vado a vestirmi*,
>     ma  nel  senso  di *essere  in  procinto*,  risponde  al  francese 
>     *aller faire*, *aller commencer*. I modi nostri *stare per* (cominciare), *ora* (si  incomincia)  nel  gergo  dei  mal  parlanti cedono il  posto  all’espressione  francese;  alla  quale  fa  riscontro assai bene l’altra, *venire di*..., fr. *venir de* (Alfredo Panzini, *Dizionario moderno*, Milano, 1905).

---

<sup>1.  Secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Rigutini), *I neologismi buoni e cattivi* di Giuseppe Rigutini e Giulio Cappuccini è stato pubblicato nel 1886.</sup>